# passed string still nodejs res.zip gives error path must be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate a zip file with file names returned by a database. I am using following code:

```
var pathforZip = '';
for(let k=0;k<filenameArray.length;k++){
    if(resultset[k].length > 0){
        pathforZip += "{ path:"+"'./"+filenameArray[k]+"', name: "+"'"+filenameArray[k]+"'},";
    }
}   

pathforZip = pathforZip.substring(0, (pathforZip.length-1));

res.zip([pathforZip],new Date().getTime()+'.zip');
```

when I print `pathforZip` and its type it gives me

```
{ path:'./begins.csv', name: 'begins.csv'},
{ path:'./ends.csv', name: 'ends.csv'},
{ path:'./crashes.csv', name: 'crashes.csv'}
```

and type as a string, but I get an error that path must be a string for res.zip

Comment: try converting it to string using toString(). For example: { path: './'+filenameArray[0].toString(), name: filenameArray[0] }

Comment: Why are you doing the loop to write `pathforZip` if you are not reading it?

Comment: @Surjeet Bhadauriya it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to create an array of objetcs to pass to res.zip, something like this:

```
let paths = [];
for(let k=0;k<filenameArray.length;k++){
    if(resultset[k].length > 0){
        paths.push({ path:'./'+filenameArray[k], name: filenameArray[k]};
    }
}   

res.zip(paths, new Date().getTime()+'.zip');
```

right?

Comment: No, you didn't @ABC :P To up vote you must click on the triangle over the 0 in the answer (top left corner). To mark as accepted, you must click in the "check" symbol, below the answer, to make it green.